# SQL Server dynamic Pivot to return one row for each category

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, dynamic-pivot

My database is SQL Server 2016. We receive source data in an Excel workbook. The worksheet that contains the source data has four columns. The `EFFDATE` is common for all load types and Trans. That is why the columns are null for the `EFFDATE`.

| FieldName | FieldData | LoadType | Trans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EFFDATE | 7/1/2021 | NULL | NULL |
| FACILITYNUMBER | 00109 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.NetworkCode_PHA_999 | 999 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.AccomCode_3 | 3 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.LAB_PHA_ReimbType | L | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.FFPHA_OPPassThru_LabRad |  | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.FFPHA_OPLCC_LabRad | 0.6555 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.Category | LAB | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| V.Category | RAD | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |

During processing, we have an application that connects to the Excel workbook via an OLEDB connection. The raw data is loaded to a database table and a trigger fires to add foreign keys for the field name and the load type. The data in the table looks as follows

| SeqNo | FileKey | FieldKey | FieldName | FieldData | LoadTypeKey | LoadType | Trans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 1002 | 1 | EFFDATE | 7/1/2021 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 97 | 1002 | 3 | FACILITYNUMBER | 00109 | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 98 | 1002 | 29 | V.NetworkCode_PHA_999 | 999 | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 99 | 1002 | 6 | V.AccomCode_3 | 3 | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 100 | 1002 | 27 | V.LAB_PHA_ReimbType | L | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 101 | 1002 | 17 | V.FFPHA_OPPassThru_LabRad |  | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 102 | 1002 | 15 | V.FFPHA_OPLCC_LabRad | 0.6555 | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 103 | 1002 | 26 | V.Category | LAB | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |
| 104 | 1002 | 32 | V.Category | RAD | 16 | V_HFR_Input_OPRate_LabRad_PHA_R | BPRH |

I have a stored procedure to dynamically pivot the rows of source data to a single row with the field names as the column headings, and the field data as the value. The problem I have with this particular set of data is there a two categories, "LAB" and "RAD". Because the SQL pivot requires an aggregate function, I only get one row returned. If I use `PIVOT (MAX(FieldData) FOR FieldName`, I get a row for "RAD". If I use `PIVOT (MIN(FieldData) FOR FieldName`, I get a row for "LAB".

How do I formulate the query to get one row each for LAB, and RAD? The desired result should match the following.

| FileKey | SeqNo | LoadTypeKey | FacilityCode | CategoryCode | Network | AccomCode | EffectDate | ReimburseType | PassThruPct | LowerCostChrg | RatioCostChrg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 97 | 16 | 00109 | LAB | 999 | 3 | 7/1/2021 | L |  | 0.6555 | NULL |
| 1002 | 97 | 16 | 00109 | RAD | 999 | 3 | 7/1/2021 | L |  | 0.6555 | NULL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty weird pivot, but you could use windowed conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      FileKey,
      SeqNo,
      LoadTypeKey,
      FacilityCode = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'FACILITYNUMBER' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey),
      CategoryCode = FieldData,
      Network = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'V.NetworkCode_PHA_999' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey),
      AccomCode = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'V.AccomCode_3' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey),
      EffectDate = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'EFFDATE' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey),
      ReimburseType = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'V.LAB_PHA_ReimbType' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey),
      PassThruPct = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'V.FFPHA_OPPassThru_LabRad' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey),
      LowerCostChrg = MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'V.FFPHA_OPLCC_LabRad' THEN FieldData END) OVER (PARTITION BY FileKey)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE FieldName = 'V.Category';
```